# Proving set of polynomials is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

If $n$ is a positive integer, is there an easy way to prove that the set $$\{(nx)^n,((n-1)x+y)^n, ((n-2)x+2y)^n,\ldots, (x+(n-1)y)^n, (ny)^n\}$$ of polynomials in two variables, $x$ and $y$, is linearly independent? I have verified it manually for $n=1,2,3$ by expanding and considering vectors of coefficients.

Comment: One thing that you could try is to consider some scalars $a_0, \dots,a_n$ such that $a_0(nx)_n+\cdots+a_n(ny)_n=0$. The set $\{(nx)^n,((n−1)x+y)^n,((n−2)x+2y)^n,\dots,(x+(n−1)y)^n,(ny)^n\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $a_0=\cdots=a_n=0$ is the only choice of scalars for which the above property holds. Using this idea, you should probably try induction on $n$,  especially since you have already verified the base case.

Answer (score 0):

Any linear dependency relation between these polynomials gives a linear dependency relation between all their derivatives with respect to $x$. We are naturally led to consider the Wronskian.

The Wronskian of these polynomials with respect to $x$ apparently is of the form $ay^m$ with $m=\binom{n+1}{2}$, though the precise exponent is not important (but it might be in the proof).

This proves that the functions are linearly independent, for all $y\ne0$.